# Net Core 3.0 and desktop applications

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-core-3.0

I just read that there is possibility to develop Windows Forms using .NET Core 3.0. Unfortunetly designer is still under development and not available. I also read that even if Windows Forms can be done using Core 3.0 that doesn't mean that it can run on either MAC or OS (same with WPF). My question is what is then the sense of it if it cannot be deployed on diffrent systems besides Windows? What type of  desktop application can i really develop to be able to deploy on various systems rather than Windows forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Microsoft seems to plan to retire the original .net and just focus on developing .netcore. My suggestion is to build application using web technologies. This way you have the best of both worlds either build web application or develop cross platform apps using something like [electron.js](https://electronjs.org/)
there are so many great apps built with electron like Vs Code or Github

Comment: I see. I am now before new development mainly target to Windows 10. I am thinking whether to target core 3.0 and choose windows forms also using designer in preview available in download option or still target .net framework. What you think?

Comment: My opinion is you better stick with .net framework If you're building a serious application, but try to separate your logic from UI code as possible in other to change to more mature winforms in net core in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are many use cases for Windows-only desktop applications, particularly in the corporate world where applications are for internal use.

If you need a cross platform application I would suggest either a web application, or you could consider [Electron](https://electronjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[AvaloniaUI](https://avaloniaui.net) (A cross platform XAML Framework for .NET Framework, .NET Core and Mono) would be a perfect choice if you are familiar with WPF.

There are many other frameworks to develop cross-platform desktop apps. You can checkout **my** github repo [electron-alternatives](https://github.com/sudhakar3697/electron-alternatives) for more cross-platform desktop development options.